# Why does sys.exit() not ignore global argument?

Tags: python, global-variables, exit, sys

So I have this code in Python, in which I defined some `global` variables and used them in different parts

```py
def compute_sigma(mellin, alpha_power, beta_power, input_path, qr_epsilon):
    global tf
    ...
    return taus, error_mellin, error_factorization

## first part
global tf
tf = ...
...
taus, error_mellin, error_factorization = compute_sigma(...)
sys.exit()
## second part
global tf ## where the warning is generated
tf = ...
...
taus, error_mellin, error_factorization = compute_sigma(...)
```

I was trying to execute first part by exiting the program at where the `sys.exit()` is, but it seems like Python is not ignoring the code completely after `sys.exit()`, it is showing the following warning message

```sh
verification.py:257: SyntaxWarning: name 'tf' is assigned to before global declaration
```

Line 257 is where the last `global` definition is.

Is there a cleverer way of exiting the program? I tried `os._exit ()`, `exit()` and `quit()`, none of them would work.

Also, please let me know if you need to reproduce the warning, I can make a toy function for you to test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you keep putting *pointless* global statements in the global scope? But yes, Python does not ignore the code after, the compiler definitely sees it and it all gets made into bytecode. Even if that code will never possibly execute.

Comment: Why would you put code after `sys.exit()`? Is the exit just temporary during development?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think now I know we only have to claim global variable once, thanks!

Comment: @Barmar The first and second parts are both time consuming and I would like to execute them separately.

Comment: @zyy the point is *you never should use `global` in the global scope*. It is pointless, it shows a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you are correct, it is good for me to realize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Don't use `global` at the global level; it doesn't serve any purpose there, and it makes the parser mad.

---

`global` only has real meaning inside a function, as it is an instruction to the compiler that the listed names refer to objects in the global scope, not local variables in the current scope.

It is a compiler directive, not really a true statement; you can't change the nature of a variable half-way through execution of the body of a function. A name is either local or global for the entire scope, regardless of where the `global` statement might occur.

Still, even if you use `global` at the global scope, it cannot occur after you have already assigned to the name, not so much for any semantic reason but there is no reason for the parser to treat it differently just because you (unnecessarily) used it in the global scope.

Comment: Yeah, if anything, I think `global` statements in the global scope should be a SyntaxError.